# Export Word document to PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word

Is it possible to convert existing Word document to PDF using iTextSharp ?

Answer (score 1):

with iTextSharp you can convert text to pdf. But you need also convert doc to text.

if you want to preserve formatting while converting documents you need to map formatting primitives(structure of doc document) too.

you need another library for working with your docs.